# Configurable Product Error on AddToCart: 'Please specify the product's options(s).'

Tags: magento-1.8, php, checkout, cart, error

Magento ver. 1.8.0.0 (CE)

Having a problem when trying to add a product to the cart. I have selected both the colour and size options (as required) and when I hit 'Add to Cart', it just returns the error 'Please specify the product's option(s).'

Please advise.

Comment: is it possible to provide a link of product page ?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot provide a link as it is on an in-house repository. I can provide excerpts of code, though.

Comment: did you checked in  backend under configurable products section , is only those 2 options are there ? is this error for all configurable products?

Comment: Yes. They're the only options for the product. The error is for all configurable  products.

Comment: can you try creating new attributes and create configurable product except `color & size`

Comment: Still the same problem.

Comment: are you using custom or 3-party theme if so switch to default theme and check.....

Comment: It still doesn't work when using the default theme.

Comment: did you done any modifications to configurable products section or any modules installed ? try disabling in app/etc/modules and also check log files once.

Comment: this product is out of stock... also did you entered quantity also ?

Comment: Black/White/Red in Size 44 is in stock. When setting the quantity to 1 with these options, it still does not work.

Comment: i found some js errors in console, i am not sure this is reason, but as it is live site,  you can't experiment on it, do you have any demo site so that you can disable some recently installed modules and check .....

Comment: You are on the demo site. Those errors are fine, though.

Comment: if this is demo site than please uninstall all 3 party modules and check through app/etc/modules folder.....

Comment: also looks like lot of guys faced same problem, did you got chance to check some [link here](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=7x7dV_zSAfGK8Qfv6amACA&gws_rd=ssl#q=magento+configurable+product+please+specify+the+product%27s+option(s))